# How to get the parent pom properties in java?

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I have an property in parent pom

```
<properties>
    <firefoxVersion>68</firefoxVersion>
    <chromeVersion>71</chromeVersion>
</properties>
```

I need to access it from the child project in java like getProperty("firefoxVersion") but it returns null.I used MavenXPP3 Reader and i was able to read the property declared in child pom.xml.

```
model.getProperties().getProperty("firefoxVersion")
```

Comment: You can read the parent pom as a file and parse it to get the value of <firefoxVersion></firefoxVersion> tag.

Comment: Are you using that for integration tests like selenium within failsafe/surefire plugin?

Comment: @khmarbaise-i just need to check whether the firefoxversion of user machine is equal with the firefoxversion which is a property in parent project.This check will happen in the child project.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use maven model, you can just load the pom file using it's path and get the property.

Something like below:

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Path_To_Your_Parent_pom.xml"));
MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
Model model = reader.read(in);
String property = model.getProperties().getProperty("Property_Name_Here");
```

Comment: Parent pom acts as a dependency (i.e)The parent project will be in artifactory & not in local path.

Comment: @kaviarasan Can you explain your scenario in detail.

Comment: @Rahul-I have kept my property firefoxVersion in parent pom which is in remote artifactory.When i try to access the properties using model i get only the properties from the child pom & not in the parent pom.

Comment: I could retreive the artifactId,Version etc of the parent pom but not the properties.